# How to run a docker image of ElasticSearch 8.4 with SSPL licence?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, elasticsearch

I am developing a spring-boot application with the aid of the new ElasticSearch Java Client 8.4. I need an ElasticSearch server running on docker with same version. Otherwise, some queries may not be performed because of incompatibility issues.

I know that ElasticSearh is no more open source from version 7.10, and has 2 kind of licences as you ca read here:
https://www.elastic.co/pricing/faq/licensing

Question is, how may I implement an Elasticseach server on Docker by using free licence? What should I do on Docker in order to choose SSPL license?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Tldr;

No need to worry, by default you will be using the free license.

## Solutions

You can set it in [the env](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#_prepare_the_environment).

Such as

```
LICENSE=basic
```

The [default is basic (SSPL license)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/license-settings.html)

> **xpack.license.self_generated.type:**
>
> (Static) Set to basic (default) to enable basic X-Pack features.